# ASP MVC Folder Hierarchy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, directory

I have a fairly large ASP MVC application. Instead of having many controllers all in the controller directory I would rather create some hierarchy. So I might have something like

```
~\Controllers\Security\
~\Controllers\Maintenance\
~\Controllers\Reports\
```

I would also like to be able to do similar with Views

```
~\Views\Security\Users\
~\Views\Security\Roles\
~\Views\Maintenance\Customer\
~\Views\Maintenance\Product\
```

Is this easily done?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something like what the "master" says in this post:

http://haacked.com/archive/0001/01/01/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx

Basically you have to create a ViewEngine to specify where to look for the views. It's a fairly simple code, just don't forget to register it in the global.asax! As for the controller part you'll have to register new routes also in the global.asax.

Answer (score 2):

The concept you're searching for is called "areas", as outlined by Phil Haack here:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: Man, I am NEVER fast enough!!

Answer (score 1):

I would think you'd need to write your own RouteHandler, which shouldn't be too tough.

A quick google search turned up: [This blog post detailing it](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2007/11/18/asp-net-mvc-framework-create-your-own-iroutehandler.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to switch to Features Folder. I've tried it (with little modifications) and it works pretty good.

Described in this post
http://timgthomas.com/2013/10/feature-folders-in-asp-net-mvc/

Code examples are in Jimmiy Bogard's repo
https://github.com/jbogard/presentations/tree/master/putyourcontrollersonadietv2

Answer (score 0):

What you really want here is for your Views folder hierarchy to match the namespace hierarchy of your controllers. You can write a custom ViewEngine to do this fairly easily  - see my [ControllerPathViewEngine project on GitHub](https://github.com/danmalcolm/ControllerPathViewEngine) for details.

I've included a snippet of the ControllerPathRazorViewEngine class to outline how it works. By intercepting the FindView / FindPartialView methods and replacing the controller name with a folder path (based on controller namespace and name), we can get it to load views from nested folders within the main Views folder.

```
    public class ControllerPathRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        //... constructors etc.

        public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
        {
            return FindUsingControllerPath(controllerContext, () => base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache));
        }

        public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
        {
            return FindUsingControllerPath(controllerContext, () => base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName, useCache));
        }

        private ViewEngineResult FindUsingControllerPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, Func<ViewEngineResult> func)
        {
            string controllerName = controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            string controllerPath = controllerPathResolver.GetPath(controllerContext.Controller.GetType());
            controllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = controllerPath;
            var result = func();
            controllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = controllerName;
            return result;
        }
    }
```